# How to get json in web2py view

Tags: jquery, json, web2py

The methods to get the data in the view of web2py does not seem working. 
I used the method mentioned in http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/10/services which is

```
    <script>
        $.getJSON('/application/default/weekdays',
          function(data){series: [{
                type: 'area',
                name: 'Response(kW)',
                data: data
            }] 
    });
```

for plotting purpose and it did not work; even the plot did not show up. I also used the method in http://www.web2pyslices.com/slice/show/1334/consuming-a-web2py-json-service-with-jquery that basically say

```
    jQuery.getJSON("{{=URL(r=request,f='call',args=['json','get_days'])}}",
        function(data){...
```

, using this the plot showed up but not the data.

Answer (score 0):

the 
        $.getJSON('/application/default/weekdays'
did not somehow work, but 
        $.getJSON('default/weekdays'
worked.